# Parsing a long/double/float number when forcing decimal separator

Tags: c#, internationalization, double, string-parsing

I am from Italy so here the decimal separator is ',' and cyphers are grouped by the char '.
To make it short I have to deal with numbers when users do not change the global format but only the separator and group char through advanced settings.

Please take a look at the following picture:
[image]

you can see that the format is still Italian but through the following advanced settings:
[image]

so you can see that despite keeping the global italian settings I force the decimal separator to be ',' and cypher group char to be '.

That being said I have to decide if a string is numeric. To do that I use the following s/r

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this string theValue)
{
    long retNum;
    return long.TryParse(theValue, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum);
}
```

the fact is that the long.TryParse fails. When theValue is "14.142135624" I get a 0 retNum value.

Tried to mess with other NumberStyles and NumberFormatInfo values but didn't get to anything useful

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out it's got nothing to do with the `NumberStyles` enumeration but with the datatype you're trying to parse into.

You are trying to parse a string that contains a decimal number into an integer value type.

You should change the call from `long.TryParse` to `decimal.TryParse` otherwise it will not work since the value is definitely not an integer by a floating point number.

Comment: As I said I've been trying NumberStyles (particularly AllowDecimalPoint, Any, Float, None, Number) but none worked.

Comment: Then - since it's a floating point number - try `decimal.TryParse()` maybe?

Comment: Great! It even works without additional parameters:  return decimal.TryParse(theValue, out retNum); Thanks!! You might want to change your answer accordingly so that I can mark it solved.

Comment: Edited the answer to match the problem.